split single CSV records into multiple JSON records
I am new to NiFi and I have been trying to figure out if my use case is possible without writing custom scripts.
I have a csv with data that looks like this (header and a couple lines of data):
id,attribute1,attribute2,attribute3
00abc,100,yes,up
01abc,150,no,down

Now, I need to convert these records in JSON. However, one CSV record equals multiple normalized JSON array records meaning the output needs to look something like this:
{
    "type": "record",
    "result": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "primary_key": "00abc",
                "field_name": "attribute1",
                "field_value": "up"
            },
            {
                "primary_key": "00abc",
                "field_name": "attribute2",
                "field_value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "primary_key": "00abc",
                "field_name": "attribute3",
                "field_value": "up"
            },
            {
                "primary_key": "01abc",
                "field_name": "attribute1",
                "field_value": "150"
            },
            {
                "primary_key": "01abc",
                "field_name": "attribute2",
                "field_value": "no"
            },
            {
                "primary_key": "01abc",
                "field_name": "attribute3",
                "field_value": "down"
            }
        ]
    }
}

I tried a number of processors (LookupRecord, SplitContent, ConvertRecord, etc.) but I just couldn't find a solution to a problem that seems so simple. All of those processors appear to expect a one-to-one relationship of records. In a custom script this would of course be easy to do, but I am truly wondering if there's any way to do this with the available processors?

i see only script option. or if number of attributes is a constant - you can convert csv to json and then use jolt processor to expand records. but i would choose script.

Your output appears to be a single top-level JSON object, is that what you intend? If instead you want separate FlowFiles with each CSV line to be converted to a single JSON object with key/value pairs (with the keys being the CSV header fields and the values being the corresponding values in the CSV row) you can use SplitRecord with a CSVReader and a JSONRecordSetWriter.

Yes, that is indeed intentional. The csv payload is essentially depicted as a JSON array, with the first value being used as the key for all following values in each line.

If you want to avoid a scripted processor, you can use ConvertRecord to change the CSV into JSON, then JoltTransformJSON to get the desired output JSON.

Thanks for the suggestion, I am not too familiar with Jolt transformation so I will check that out!
